# Implementing BST backed up by Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to implement bst using array, but no luck:

```
class BST {

  constructor() {
    this.array =[]
    this.rootSet = false;
    this.index = 0
  }

  getLeft(index) {
    return (2 * index) + 1
  }

  getRight(index) {
    return 2 * (index + 1)
  }

  getParent(index) {
    return index >>> 1
  }

  insert(value) {
    if (!this.rootSet) {
      this.rootSet = true
      this.array = [value]
      this.index++;
    } else {
      // inserts recursively.
      this.insertHelper(this.getParent(0), value);
    }
  }
  
  // helper function to insert recursively.
  insertHelper(index, value) {
    if (value < this.array[index] && this.array[this.getLeft(index)] === undefined) {
      this.array[this.getLeft(index)] = value
    } else if (value >= this.array[index] && this.array[this.getRight(index)] === undefined) {
      this.array[this.getRight(index)] = value
    } else {
      if (value < this.array[index]) {
        this.insertHelper(this.getLeft(index), value);
      } else {
        this.insertHelper(this.getRight(index), value);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried the following:

```
a.insert(2)
a.insert(0)
a.insert(3)
a.insert(10)
a.insert(30)



a.array // [2, 0, 3, empty × 3, 10, empty × 7, 30]
```

`a.array` doesn't look correct. Not sure where I'm making the mistake.

Comment: What doesn't look correct about it? What are you expecting?

Comment: `this.array = [value]` So you are replacing array with a new array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result looks correct to me. The reason for the sparsity is that this is a typical characteristic of array-based backing structures for binary trees. If the tree isn't complete, there are wasted entries due to the empty elements representing unfilled subtrees. Since BSTs typically need [balancing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree) to retain optimal time complexity, a linked node-based approach is the typical solution, which makes rotation and balancing easier.

Typically, the array backing structure is used for [binary heaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)#Implementation) which benefit from the memory layout and speed of arrays over heap-allocated nodes and pointers; the heap operations don't permit sparsity and are easy to reason about in a linear structure using the same parent-child relationship you've used here.

Having said that, you can simplify your code considerably:

```js
class BST {
  constructor() {
    this.array = [];
  }

  insert(value, ix=0) {
    if (this.array[ix] === undefined) {
      this.array[ix] = value;
    }
    else if (value < this.array[ix]) {
      this.insert(value, ix * 2 + 1);
    }
    else {
      this.insert(value, ix * 2 + 2);
    }
  }
}

/*
    2
   / \
  0   3
       \
        10
         \
          30
*/
const bst = new BST();
[2, 0, 3, 10, 30].forEach(e => bst.insert(e));
console.log(bst.array);
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't checked the code but the result looks correct to me.
The first item in the array is the root. Then the next two are the rank 1 nodes
then the next 4 are the rank 2 nodes.
then the next 8 are the rank 4 nodes
Your result should be

[image: 2 / 0 3 10 30]